# Just installed Ubuntu for first time, booted fine at first but now won't boot

Tags: boot

Booted fine after first restart, Windows boots fine, but I'm getting stuck on this screen now

[image]

Comment: try to disable fastboot in windows

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something may have been corrupted for some reason when it installed.

Try this:

1. Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD;
2. Open/Run Terminal.
3. Type:

sudo fdisk -l

4. Press Enter. You should get an output like the one below:

[image: fdisk output]

What we're looking for here is the device name of your hard drive. If you only have one hard drive, typically it will be **/dev/sda**. We just need the first letters of the drive, the number isn't as needed for this situation.

5. Type:

   sudo fsck /dev/sda (or your device name)
6. Then press ENTER.
7. Restart the system and boot normally.

Read more: http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html#ixzz48xV8Q2Nn